Python tests failing due to testcontainers-postgres connection refused
I am trying to run integration tests by using PostgresContainer from the testcontainers module in Python. These tests are part of the CI workflow on Github Actions but they are failing due to the following error:

conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 32773 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 32773 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
/home/runner/.cache/pants/named_caches/pex_root/venvs/s/9a6036af/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/init.py:122: OperationalError

This error originates from the following line:

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

My session.py file looks like this:
"""Session module to create a session for the PostgreSQL database."""
from os import environ  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module

import psycopg2  # type: ignore # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, sessionmaker
from testcontainers.postgres import PostgresContainer  # type: ignore

if environ.get("PYTHON_ENV") == "test":
    with PostgresContainer(image="postgres:13") as _postgres:
        DATABASE_URL = _postgres.get_connection_url()
else:
    DATABASE_URL = environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "")

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


# pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    """Base class for the database models.

    This is used instead of declarative_base() because typing tools understand it.
    https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#step-one-orm-declarative-base-is-superseded-by-orm-declarativebase
    """

The error originates in the following fixture I am using:
@fixture(scope="function", name="_db_session")
def fixture_db_session():
    """Create a new session for each test case."""
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    session = SessionLocal()
    session.begin()
    yield session
    session.rollback()
    session.close()
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)

Also I have checked the DATABASE_URL for testcontainer and it looks like this:

***localhost:32773/test

I'm not sure if this DATABASE_URL is normal for testcontainers. Any suggestions on fixing this connection refused error are welcome. Thanks.
